DNSSEC and Response Policy Zones
I have configured an RPZ using bind, but If I try to do queries using DNSSEC it fails. The idea was just to overwrite some subdomains of my domain to make them accessible on the LAN behind the NAT. Nevertheless, after enabling DNSSEC on my domain it no longer works. I can disable DNSSEC on all my devices, but I think that's not an option.
How can I set up the RPZ to be able to use DNSSEC? Or can I make an exception for that domain?
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    recursion yes;
    listen-on { 192.168.1.11; 127.0.0.1; };
    allow-transfer { 192.168.1.0/24; };
    # Overriding local
    response-policy {
        zone "rpz";
    } break-dnssec yes;
    minimal-responses yes;

    forwarders {
        1.1.1.1;
        1.0.0.1;
    };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};

zone "rpz" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.rpz";
};

